# Can I use the area of the ellipse instead of the integral

Tags: calculus

The area of a triangle is defined as  $1/2$ * Area of a rectangle.

So suppose I want to find the area under the [curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%201-x%5E2) $1 - x^2$ on the interval $[-1, 1]$ , can I plot [another curve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E2-1) say, $x^2 - 1$ (which is sort of a reflection of the first parabola), calculate the area of this new ellipse and then divide it by 2?

Comment: Yes, except that it's not an ellipse...

Comment: @HansLundmark what is it then?

Comment: Well, it's simply the union of two parabola-shaped pieces (whose areas are most easily found by integration).

Comment: @HansLundmark can't see the difference between that and a ellipse

Comment: An ellipse has equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. Your curve has equation $x^2 + y = 1$. Not the differences in power of $y$.

Comment: Besides the excellent algebraic explanation by md2perpe, do you *really* think that [this picture of your region](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs(y)+%5Cle+1-x%5E2) looks like an ellipse...?